# Why the paths coming up wrong when as far as I can tell they are not?

Tags: path, header, footer, path-finding

When pathing my footer and header, the pathing comes up wrong. It is in components and in src. It doesnt seem to matter how I word it. Please Advise.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import Services from './components/pages/Services';
import Portfolio from './components/pages/Portfolio';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import VerticalNavBar from './components/VerticalNavBar';
```

This is what I would like, because it makes sense.

[showing what the visual code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLt5X.png)